# more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression problem

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update a column in one database with a query:
[Here the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHKjY.png)

and this is the output i think it is impossible to asign a query to a field but what is the solution for that plz.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w902r.png)

Comment: 1) Please don't post screenshots. 2) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

= can be used when we are pretty sure that the subquery returns only 1 value.
When we are not sure whether subquery returns more than 1 value, we will have to use IN to accommodate all values or simply use TOP 1 to limit the equality matching to one value:

```
UPDATE  mascir_fiche SET partner = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM hr_employee WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM hr_employee));
```

With Limit:

```
UPDATE  mascir_fiche SET artner = (SELECT id FROM hr_employee WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM hr_employee) limit 1);
```

Comment: but it's give an error and this is the error . ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 2: SET partner = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM hr_employee

Comment: Give it a try with limit 1:

Comment: UPDATE mascir_fiche
SET  partner = (SELECT id FROM hr_employee WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM hr_employee) limit 1);

Comment: But in the field partner it's give just a value and this is not correct because in the partner must be return a a lot of values.

Comment: As per your query, the same value say xyz will be set to the partner field for all records present in mascir_fiche table.

Comment: but please I want each attribute partner in the mascir_fiche table to have them under its authority and to find that it needs to be that I was forced to retrive all the ids from the table hr_employee that has parent_id field equals name field from the table mascir_fiche can you give a solution for that

Comment: Can you please share table schema's and some sample data along with sample output for understanding purpose?

Comment: can you give the name on one of your social account to share with you if you mind

Comment: You can message me on linkedin.com/in/rajanpatekar